# How can I specify different regexp for a single field using yup?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form, yup

I have an input that I wanna validate to only accept Google Maps type of URL.
AFAIK, I have three posible outputs for google maps that I want to accept as valid, being these:

1. https://maps.app.goo.gl/SomeString (for google maps app)
2. https://www.google.com.mx/maps/SomeReallyBigStringAndOtherParams (I only want to care for https://www.google.com.mx/maps/)
3. https://goo.gl/maps/SomeString (when sharing directly from maps)

Right now I can handle the first scenario, and I thing I can make my way out of the regular expressions, but my question is how to enable multiple regexp validations using Yup validator and React hook forms. I have the following:

```
const areaSchema = yup.object().shape({
...
    urlGoogleMaps: yup.string()
        .matches(/^https\:\/\/goo\.gl\/maps\//, 'Invalid google maps URL')
        .required(requiredMessage),
...
});
```

I've tried using different matches, but it doesn't work because it tries to validate both of matches conditions as true:

Having an input as https://goo.gl/maps/

```
const areaSchema = yup.object().shape({
...
    urlGoogleMaps: yup.string()
        .matches(/^https\:\/\/goo\.gl\/maps\//, 'Invalid google maps URL') * Checks
        .matches(/^https\:\/\/goo\.gl\/secondMaps\//, 'Invalid google maps URL') * Doesn't check, so its invalid
        .required(requiredMessage),
...
});
```

Is there a way to validate multiple strings using multiple .matches()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `test` work?

```
const urlValidationSchema = Yup.string().test(
  'is-valid-url',
  'invalid-url',
  (value) => 
    /^(http|https):\/\/google\.com$/.test(value) ||
    /^(http|https):\/\/secondmaps\.com$/.test(value) ||
    /^(http|https):\/\/somethingelse\.com$/.test(value)
)
.required(requiredMessage);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay! But yes, this approach indeed works, thank you very much!